# How can I move the position of a label inside a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I just started using TikZ an it's amazing. But I can't find out how to change the position of the label inside a node. At the moment I've:

```
\node (DataAccess) at (0,2) [draw,thick,minimum width=8cm,minimum height=2cm,
      align=center, rounded corners] {Datenzugriff};
```

But I'd like to have the text in the upper center (but inside) of the rectangle. Any idea?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `text depth`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (DataAccess) at (0,2) [draw,thick,minimum width=8cm,minimum height=2cm, align=center, text depth=2cm, rounded corners, label=below:User space] {Datenzugriff};\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]